# Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker - binding to angular model doesn't work after 'dp.change'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Im trying to use `Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker` from `eonasdan`. Everything is working, but I've met the problem with binding the actual date inside the input to angular ng-model. When I'm changing the data using the picker, 'dp.change' event is working, date is changing inside the input, but I have to press spacebar or any other key to achive ng-model update detection.

Some peace of code:

*JS with angular directive:*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('feedApp');

    module.directive('datetimepicker', [
        '$timeout',
        function ($timeout) {
            return {
                require: '?ngModel',
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    options: '@',
                    onChange: '&',
                    onClick: '&'
                },
                link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
                    $($element).on('dp.change', function () {
                        //alert("change");
                        $timeout(function () {
                            var dtp = $element.data('DateTimePicker');
                            controller.$setViewValue(dtp.date());
                            $scope.onChange();
                        });
                    });

                    $($element).on('click', function () {
                        $scope.onClick();
                    });

                    controller.$render = function () {
                        if (!!controller) {
                            if (controller.$viewValue === undefined) {
                                controller.$viewValue = null;
                            }
                            else if (!(controller.$viewValue instanceof moment)) {
                                controller.$viewValue = moment(controller.$viewValue);
                            }
                            $($element).data('DateTimePicker').date(controller.$viewValue);
                        }
                    };

                    $($element).datetimepicker($scope.$eval($attrs.options));
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

*HTML:*

```
<div style="max-width: 250px">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" options="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm', locale:'pl'}" datetimepicker ng-model="feed.reminderDateTime" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to fix this ? I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue while back. Dont have the source code to reference but I do remember it was something like such.

as your ng-model is `ng-model="feed.reminderDateTime"`

In your controller you should do this `$scope.feed = {reminderDateTime:''};`

Then you should be able to access it via such `$scope.feed.reminderDateTime`

Let me know how that goes

Answer (score 0):

require ('datetimepicker');

```
Vue.directive('datetimepicker', {
    twoWay: true, //very important to bind the modeldata
    bind: function () {
        $(this.el).datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',    //see moment for more valid date time formats
            useCurrent: false
        }).on('dp.change', function (value) {
            //todo: do the required changed to the value here 
        });
    },
    update: function (value) {
        $(this.el).val(value).trigger('dp.change');
    },
    unbind: function () {
        $(this.el).off().datetimepicker('destroy');
    }
});
```